# How did David create the face hugger pods/eggs when previously only a queen was seen doing that?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In Alien Covenant, David lures Captain Oram into a room where we see what look like the eggs that only queens lay (refer to Aliens and Alien Resurrection films). David later admits that he has been tinkering with the pathogen, and the various forms that are mutated from its hosts, but I can see no link to an actual egg layer...unless there is maybe something on that planet, that again David created, that, to quote Bishop, "Maybe it's something we haven't seen yet."

Comment: Been asking myself the same thing, but on the other hand, maybe some pregnant engineer woman just gave birth to one like Shaw did at the end of Prometheus?

Comment: Shaw gave birth to a Trilobite.  From what I have heard, Ridley Scott has retconed the queens altogether (do not quote me on that).

Comment: There is one possible way to answer this that keeps the queens in the story.  It's evolution.  When you look at the problem of the chicken and the egg, the evolutionary answer is "the egg came first because evolution is a process that happens from generation to generation"  meaning that a long time ago something that was not a chicken laid a chicken egg.  So maybe something that was not a queen (David) made the face-hugger eggs, and the xenomorphs developed their own reproductive cycle, thus resulting in the creation of the Queen.